# Is it OK to have a test account for a developing client?

Tags: support, feature-request, java, testing

I'm currently trying to implement an agorava component for Stackoverflow, and for testing purpose, i would like to create a test account, which would have one question asked, and would maybe send comments on that question. Is it possible ? If so on which site of the StackOverflow galaxy ?

Comment: Good question. Most Social Media don't provide test account (in fact I don't know one that does). But some of them provides "sandbox" mode in the application declared to use their API (LinkedIn or Facebook do so). In this mode only declared accounts can see contribution done through the application.